# How to create a SQL Server user that can restore databases to a database server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a new user that can create new databases on my database server.

I've tried:

```
CREATE LOGIN [my_db_restore_user] WITH PASSWORD = 'passwordhere';
GRANT ALTER ON ROLE::[dbcreator] TO [my_db_restore_user] WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Which results in: Cannot find the object 'dbcreator', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I've also tried:

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE [dbcreator] ADD MEMBER [my_db_restore_user];
```

```
GRANT ALTER ON SERVER ROLE::dbcreator TO my_db_restore_user ;
```

but all result in the same error.

How can I create a server level user that can create databases on the server for restoring purposes. The user will also need to create users on the new databases too.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst you *can* use the dbcreator role, I wouldn't personally. It can drop existing databases, and alter them.

In fact I tend to stay away from fixed server roles completely, in favour of designing my own server roles with appropriate rights.

I would do the following to grant the specific, granular right you need:

```
GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO [my_db_restore_user];
```

This should allow them to create databases only. Obviously it's worth thinking about the fact that this login then becomes the owner of that database and can subsequently drop it.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I create a server level user that can create databases on the server for restoring purposes. The user will also need to create users on the new databases too.

Just want to make it clear on SQL Server terminology, there is NO **User** available in server level. Server level security principals contains the `Logins`, and `users` are databases security principals, user can be associated with logins, so the login directly won't get the access on database unless a user inside the database associated with login.

However, in your case, you may want to try following to achieve your requirement. In-order to execute following commands you must be either using `sa` or any login that is already part of `sysadmin` server role.

```
--- you must use strong password that meets password policy, otherwise run "CHECK_POLICY= OFF"
CREATE LOGIN [my_db_restore_user] WITH PASSWORD = 'passwordhere';

--- policy off  
CREATE LOGIN [my_db_restore_user] WITH PASSWORD = 'passwordhere',  Check_policy = off;


ALTER SERVER ROLE dbcreator ADD MEMBER [my_db_restore_user];

ALTER SERVER ROLE securityadmin ADD MEMBER [my_db_restore_user];
```

It's good that you trying to limit logins to be part of `sysadmin` [fixed server role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017) which has ultimate access on SQL Server, keep maintain that!

Comment: Thanks @Shekar Kola - I did try ALTER SERVER ROLE dbcreator ADD MEMBER [..] but it resulted in "Cannot alter the server role 'dbcreator', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." - I am logged in as the database admin.

Comment: Hello @user188749, there is NO chance that the `dbcreator` does not exist. something might have wrong with permissions, are you sure when you say the current user is "database admin" is it already part of `sysadmin` role? You can quickly verify it by executing `select IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin')` from same user session. (Result: **1** =Got the permissions, **0** = NO permissions)

Comment: I got a 0, but I'm using the Master username, created as part of the db creation.

Comment: It means you're not part of `sysadmin` server role, and it's not possible to do `ALTER SERVER ROLE` (as mentioned in my answer), the user that you were using might be `db_owner` which got full permissions on particular database, but that doesn't mean you can alter server level permissions